# How to avoid duplicate names of class and method?

Tags: c++, naming

Currently I use same convention for class names and method names. They have a leading capital letter without prefix. And I don't use "Get" prefix to get an attribute. However, I meet a name conflict problem in the following code

```
class Material
{};

class Background
{
public:
    Material* Material() const             {return m_material;}  // Name conflict
    void SetMaterial(Material* material)   {m_material = material;}

private:
    Material* m_material;
};
```

What is the easiest way to solve the problem but keeping or with minimum modification of my conventions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use upper case class names and camelCased members and method names.

Comment: What's so bad with using a "Get" prefix anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the **easiest** way to solve the problem but keeping or with
>   minimum modification of my conventions?

The *easiest* way might be to slightly modify the convention, such as start method names with lowercase.

BTW, I like that you are not using the word "get" in the accessor method. In the same spirit, you may drop the word "set" in the mutator method (here, `SetMaterial()`). The signature would be sufficient to distinguish the accessor and mutator.

If you like them, you would reach at:

```
class Material
{};

class Background
{
public:
    Material* material() const          {return m_material;}
    void material(Material* material)   {m_material = material;}

private:
    Material* m_material;
};
```

Comment: out of curiosity (I know it's ultimately personal preference): Why do you prefer dropping get/set?

Comment: That's a good question, glad that you asked! To me, the "get" or "set" appear superfluous since the usage makes it clear and unambiguous whether the code is getting or setting. Also, I personally find `if( bg.material() == foo )` easier and fluent
to read, compared to `if( bg.getMaterial() == foo )`.

Answer (score 1):

It is *unusual* to capitalise method names.

Comment: In C++ anyway... It's all too common in .NET languages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Qt library. It uses almost the same conventions as you and it is the best piece of code I've ever seen. Only difference I see is capital letter at begin of method names. So change yours convention to match theirs and you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

You are bitten by not following good naming rules.

To name a function, use a strong verb followed by an object A procedure with functional cohesion usually performs an operation on an object. The name should reflect what the procedure does, and an operation on an object implies a verb-plus-object name. GetMaterial(), SetMaterial, PrintDocument(), CalcMonthlyRevenues(), CheckOrderlnfo(), and RepaginateDocument() are samples of good procedure names.

> What is the easiest way to solve the problem but keeping or with minimum modification of my conventions?

Simply add an action in front of object as function name:

```
Material* GetMaterial() const {return m_material;}
```